# How to download pdf file from data loaded from ajax or fetch calling express route that call our Api via axios?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, axios, fetch

I try to download a pdf file generated by our API.

THE FLOW:
Clicking a "Dowload" button trigger a function that fetch an express route.
The route call our API via axios.
The API generate a pdf and return a raw data pdf file (string).
The route get the response of axios.
To send this response back to the fetch, I put the response in an object {pdf: response} and sent it back with res.json({pdf: response}).
In the fetch.then(), I need to transform the response into blob and use URL.createObjectURL on it to create an invisvible donwload link to trigger click on it and start download.

THE PROBLEM:
The response sent by res.json({pdf: response}) cannot be transformed into blob because it's not the pdf data, it's an json containing the pdf data.

Action triggered by the button click:

```
var url = "/routePath";

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        // the filename you want
        a.download = couponName + '.pdf';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Express route handling on server side:

```
router.get('/routePath', async function(req, res, next) {

    const pdf = await Api.send(req, 'entity', 'action', {data}, {});
    res.json({pdf: pdf});
});
```

Call via Axios:

```
const config = require(`../config/config.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`);
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    send: async function(req, entity, action, data, pathValues){
        let response = false;

        try {
            // Prepare headers
            let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
            
            // Request
            let axiosConfig = {
                method: 'get',
                headers,
                url: path,
                data: data,
                validateStatus: false
            };
            axiosConfig.params = data;

            response = await axios(axiosConfig);

            if (response.data == '') response.data = {};
            response = response.data;
            response.callSuccess = true;
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
            if (error.response){

                response = error.response.data;
                response.callSuccess = false;
                console.error(response);
            }
            else {
                console.error(error);
            }
            
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share how you are generating the PDF?

Comment: I don't have access to the API files.

Answer (score 1):

Client side:

I switched Fetch for Ajax to get more compatility (ie).
I also transform with base64ToArrayBuffer, the recieved pdf data to be able to transform it into blob.

```
[...]
var url = "/routePath";

    $.ajax({ url: url })
    .done(function(pdf) {
        const arraybuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(pdf);
        const blob = new Blob([arraybuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = url;
        a.download = 'GoCoupons.' + couponName + '.pdf';
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    })

    [...]

function base64ToArrayBuffer(data) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(data);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Server side:

Instead of returning a json, I send the pdf response from our API.

```
router.get('/routePath', async function(req, res, next) {
    const pdf = await Api.send(req, 'entity', 'action', {data}, {});
    res.send(pdf);
});
```

The Axios call is still the same

```
const config = require(`../config/config.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.json`);
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    send: async function(req, entity, action, data, pathValues){
        let response = false;

        try {
            // Prepare headers
            let headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
            
            // Request
            let axiosConfig = {
                method: 'get',
                headers,
                url: path,
                data: data,
                validateStatus: false
            };
            axiosConfig.params = data;

            response = await axios(axiosConfig);

            if (response.data == '') response.data = {};
            response = response.data;
            response.callSuccess = true;
        } catch(error) {
            console.error(error);
            if (error.response){

                response = error.response.data;
                response.callSuccess = false;
                console.error(response);
            }
            else {
                console.error(error);
            }
            
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```